# Sklearn - Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [16512, 4128]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Going through the second chapter of Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow, running to the error stated above.  This happens when I try to implement the following line:

```
linReg.fit(housingPrepared, housing_labels)
```

Researching online it looks like it has to do something with the dimensions of my features and my labels not matching up.  Printing the shape of housingPrepared (X) and housing_labels (Y) yields the following result:

(16512, 16) (4128,)

I've spent the last hour going through line by line to see if I missed a line in this chapter, can't find anything.  Wondering if someone here might have an intuition on where a potential solution for this problem could be.

Thank you so much in advance.  All my code up to the problem line is posted below:

```
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from zlib import crc32
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedShuffleSplit
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from CategoricalEncoder import CategoricalEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets","housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetchHousingData(housingUrl=HOUSING_URL, housingPath=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housingPath):
        os.makedirs(housingPath)
    tgzPath = os.path.join(housingPath, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housingUrl, tgzPath)
    housingTgz = tarfile.open(tgzPath)
    housingTgz.extractall(path=housingPath)
    housingTgz.close()

def loadHousingData(housingPath=HOUSING_PATH):
    return pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv")

housing = loadHousingData()
#plt.hist(housing['longitude'],bins=50)
#plt.show()

def splitTrainTesT(data, testRatio):
    shuffled_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
    testSetSize = int(len(data)* testRatio)
    testIndices = shuffled_indices[:testSetSize]
    trainIndices = shuffled_indices[testSetSize:]
    return data.iloc[trainIndices], data.iloc[testIndices]

def testSetCheck(identifier, testRatio):
    return crc32(np.int64(identifier)) & 0xffffffff < testRatio * 2 ** 32

def splitTrainTestByID(data, testRatio, idColumn):
    ids = data[idColumn]
    inTestSet = ids.apply(lambda id_: testSetCheck(id_, testRatio))
    return data.loc[~inTestSet], data.loc[inTestSet]


#housingWithID = housing.reset_index()
#trainSet, testSet = splitTrainTestByID(housingWithID,0.2,"index")

trainSet, testSet = train_test_split(housing,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

housing["income_cat"] = np.ceil(housing["median_income"]/1.5)
housing["income_cat"].where(housing["income_cat"] < 5, 5.0, inplace=True)

#plt.hist(housing["income_cat"])
#plt.show()

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
for trainIndex, testIndex in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    stratTrainSet = housing.loc[trainIndex]
    stratTestSet = housing.loc[testIndex]

for set in (stratTrainSet, stratTestSet):
    set.drop("income_cat", axis=1, inplace=True)

housing = stratTrainSet.copy()
#print(housing)

#plt.scatter(x=housing["latitude"],y=housing["longitude"], alpha=0.4)
#plt.show()

corr_matrix = housing.corr()
#print(corr_matrix["median_house_value"].sort_values(ascending=False))

#attribues = ["median_house_value", "median_income", "total_rooms", "housing_median_age"]
#scatter_matrix(housing[attribues], figsize=(12,8))
#plt.show()

""" PREPARING DATA FOR MACHINE LEARNING ALGORITHMS"""
housing = stratTrainSet.drop("median_house_value", axis=1)
housing_labels = stratTestSet["median_house_value"].copy()


housing.dropna(subset=["total_bedrooms"])
imputer = Imputer(strategy="median")
housingNum = housing.drop("ocean_proximity", axis=1)
imputer.fit(housingNum)

X = imputer.transform(housingNum)
housingTr = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=housingNum.columns)

housingCat = housing["ocean_proximity"]
housingCatEncoded, housingCategories = housingCat.factorize()

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
housingCat1Hot = encoder.fit_transform(housingCatEncoded.reshape(-1,1))


"""Custom Transformers For Rooms Per Household, etc"""
roomsIX, bedroomsIX, populationIX, householdsIX = 3,4,5,6

class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, addBedroomsPerRoom = True):
        self.addBedroomsPerRoom = addBedroomsPerRoom
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        roomsPerHousehold = X[:,roomsIX]/X[:,householdsIX]
        populationPerHousehold = X[:,populationIX]/X[:,householdsIX]
        if self.addBedroomsPerRoom:
            bedroomsPerRoom = X[:,bedroomsIX]/X[:,roomsIX]
            return np.c_[X, roomsPerHousehold, populationPerHousehold, bedroomsPerRoom]
        else:
            return np.c_[X, roomsPerHousehold, populationPerHousehold]

attrAdder = CombinedAttributesAdder(addBedroomsPerRoom=False)
housingExtraAttribs = attrAdder.transform(housing.values)

numPipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', Imputer(strategy='median')),
                        ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
                        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
                        ])

housingNumTr = numPipeline.fit_transform(housingNum)

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attributeNames):
        self.attributeNames = attributeNames
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attributeNames].values


numAttribs = list(housingNum)
catAttribs = ["ocean_proximity"]

numPipeline = Pipeline([('selector', DataFrameSelector(numAttribs)),
                        ('imputer', Imputer(strategy='median')),
                        ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
                        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),])

"""UPDATE SKLEARN TO INCLUDE CATEGORICAL ENCODER LIBRARY"""
catPipeline = Pipeline([('selector', DataFrameSelector(catAttribs)),
                        ('cat_encoder', CategoricalEncoder(encoding='onehot-dense')),
                        ])

fullPipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[("num_pipeline", numPipeline), ("cat_pipeline", catPipeline),])

housingPrepared = fullPipeline.fit_transform(housing)



linReg = LinearRegression()

print(housingPrepared.shape, housing_labels.shape)
linReg.fit(housingPrepared, housing_labels)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in these two lines:

```
housing = stratTrainSet.drop("median_house_value", axis=1)
housing_labels = stratTestSet["median_house_value"].copy()
```

Change it to:

```
housing = stratTrainSet.drop("median_house_value", axis=1)
housing_labels = stratTrainSet["median_house_value"].copy()
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: Derp, what a dumb mistake.  Thank you so much.